# After archiving an iOS app Xcode is not using the the correct provision and uses XC:* instead

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, provisioning, entitlements

When archiving my app for submission to the app store I am running into a problem getting the correct entitlements. I seem to be missing the push notification entitlement. I have the correct provision but when I archive the app it goes to the XC:* provision which cannot have push notifications and I think is the the source of the problem. I'm stumped. This has happened to me when I first started developing for iOS and I was able to solve it by just downloading all the provisions in the account section of preferences.That has not worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can choose the correct provisioning. To do that go to: Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile.

Comment: I can't find the correct 'XC:com.companyName.appName' from the options given. It would automatically get the correct provisioning until Friday afternoon when it just stopped. I have the correct distribution provision, the correct p12 and pem cert. The bundle in Xcode matches the bundle on iTunes connect, I don't know what possibly could have changed since Friday.